# How to include a git tag in my frontend build when using `skaffold build` in a bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: docker, vue.js, google-cloud-build, bitbucket-pipelines, skaffold

I am trying to get the image tag in the build process, as a kind of version for the frontend I am building. My frontend code is in Vue/Vite. Currently, this is what I get for the version:

```
<NO VALUE>
```

Here is my bitbucket pipeine build:

```
    - step: &build
          name: Build Image on Google
          image: gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold:latest
          trigger: manual
          script:
            - [setup/configure gcloud command. omitted.]
            - skaffold build
```

Here is my skaffold file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta12
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: my-frontend-test
build:
  artifacts:
    - image: my.docker.repo/my-org/my-frontend-test
      context: ./
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
        buildArgs:
          VITE_APP_VERSION: "{{.IMAGE_TAG}}"
  googleCloudBuild:
    projectId: my-frontend-test
    timeout: 20000s
  tagPolicy:
    customTemplate:
      template: "{{.TIMESTAMP}}-{{.COMMIT}}"
      components:
        - name: TIMESTAMP
          dateTime:
            format: "200601021504"
            timezone: America/New_York
        - name: COMMIT
          gitCommit:
            variant: AbbrevCommitSha
```

Here is my docker file:

```
ARG BASE=my.docker.repo/my-org/my-frontend-test-base:latest
FROM $BASE as base-image

WORKDIR /build/frontend

COPY . /build/frontend/
RUN pnpm config set strict-peer-dependencies=false && pnpm install

ARG VITE_APP_VERSION
ENV VITE_APP_VERSION=$VITE_APP_VERSION
RUN echo "IMAGE TAG IS: ${VITE_APP_VERSION}"
RUN echo "VITE_APP_VERSION=${VITE_APP_VERSION}" >> .env
RUN pnpm build
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use tag pipelines, you can use the `BITBUCKET_TAG` environment variable:

```
pipelines:
  tags:
    '**':
      - step: &build
          script:
            - # ...
            - export IMAGE_TAG=$BITBUCKET_TAG
            - skaffold build
```

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-start-conditions/#Tags